# Is there an autocorrect feature in Expression Web 3 and if so how can I turn it off?

Tags: expression-web, microsoft-expression-web

I have an aspx page that starts with the code

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="~/Views/
```

Every time I hit the save button, the text is changed to

```
<%@ Page Title="" Language="C#" MasterPageFile="Views/
```

(with the tilde and slash missing).

Why does Expression Web 3 do this and how can I turn this off?